# colorful shape on git console during push

Tags: git, bitbucket

I get this colorful shape when I push to my remote branch. It has never happened before and I have been working on this branch for a long time. It happened twice and then stopped happening again. I am not sure what it means. Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question! And the answer surprisingly, and for once, resides in **Politics**.

Source: http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2015/06/gay-marriage-america

[image: http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2015/06/gay-marriage-america]

Answer (score 1):

The remote admin added rainbow colors celebrating diversity inspired by a landmark Supreme Court decision.